# how to store Large JSON Data from Server to SQLTE Android?

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite, okhttp

i have this app where i download different tables from server and store them in SQLITE. the data coming from the server is List Of Queries in the form like "INSERT INTO XYZ(A,B,C) VALUES (X,Y,Z)". following is the function in am using for downloading and storing the tables:

```
 fun synchronizeWithServer(phone: String, tableName: String , dialogue : LoadingDialog) {
        val activity = context as Activity
        val url =
            "http://OrderingSystem.svc/SyncDev?phid=$phone&table=$tableName"
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val listServer = ArrayList<String>()
                    val jsonData = response.body?.string()
                    val jasonArray = JSONArray(jsonData)
                    for (k in 0 until jasonArray.length()) {
                        listServer.add(jasonArray[k].toString())
                    }
                    activity.runOnUiThread {
                        when (tableName) {
                            "customer" -> {
                                val db = DbHelper(context)
                                for (item in listServer) {
                                    db.addServerData(item)
                                }
                                db.close()
                                listServer.clear()
                            }
                            "items" -> {
                                val db = UtilityDB(context)
                                for (item in listServer) {
                                    db.addServerData(item)
                                }
                                db.close()
                                listServer.clear()
                            }
                            "rates" -> {
                                val db = UtilityDB(context)
                                for (item in listServer) {
                                    db.addServerData(item)
                                    
                                }
                                db.close()
                                listServer.clear()
                            }
                            "ledger" -> {
                                val db = Ledgers(context)
                                for (item in listServer ) {
                                    db.addServerData(item)
                                }
                                db.close()
                                listServer.clear()
                                dialogue.stopLoading()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

some of the Tables coming from server are soo huge like ledger table, when I try to save it into SQLITE my application is jammed , then after sometime it crashes . How can I store that Large data into SQLITE ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just don't do any work with your database on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Just move all your database work out of `runOnUiThread` and run only UI work on the main thread (`dialogue.stopLoading()`):

```
fun synchronizeWithServer(phone: String, tableName: String , dialogue : LoadingDialog) {
    val activity = context as Activity
    val url =
        "http://OrderingSystem.svc/SyncDev?phid=$phone&table=$tableName"
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val listServer = ArrayList<String>()
                val jsonData = response.body?.string()
                val jasonArray = JSONArray(jsonData)
                for (k in 0 until jasonArray.length()) {
                    listServer.add(jasonArray[k].toString())
                }
                when (tableName) {
                    "customer" -> {
                        val db = DbHelper(context)
                        for (item in listServer) {
                            db.addServerData(item)
                        }
                        db.close()
                        listServer.clear()
                    }
                    "items" -> {
                        val db = UtilityDB(context)
                        for (item in listServer) {
                            db.addServerData(item)
                        }
                        db.close()
                        listServer.clear()
                    }
                    "rates" -> {
                        val db = UtilityDB(context)
                        for (item in listServer) {
                            db.addServerData(item)

                        }
                        db.close()
                        listServer.clear()
                    }
                    "ledger" -> {
                        val db = Ledgers(context)
                        for (item in listServer) {
                            db.addServerData(item)
                        }
                        db.close()
                        listServer.clear()
                        
                        activity.runOnUiThread {
                            dialogue.stopLoading()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```